# IntelliJ losing Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I replaced a dependency in my Gradle file in an IntelliJ project.  It was a library that did something similar to the one I replaced which doesn't have any effect on this issue.  When I check .gradle cache (and the .m2 cache) the dependency is there and that allows the project to build successfully from the command line using gradle commands.  However, IntelliJ will not update its external libraries with the new dependency.

Has anyone had this happen and know an easy solution.  The last time it happened I ended up wiping IntelliJ from my Mac and reinstalling and that solved the problem.  Seems like a pretty crucial issue and would love to submit to Jetbrains as well.

Comment: I have used Intellij and gradle for 3 years, and never encountered this. do If you run Gradle refresh from Intellij your build.gradle file does not need to have the intellij plugin in gradle, if you run gradle from the command line you need the plugin in order to generate libraries, and artifacts. If you delete the library in the project settings, does it reappear when you refresh gradle.

Comment: I've only recently learned about the Gradle IntelliJ plugin.  Gave that a try and the files it created were missing the dependency as well.  It's literally a bug directly associated with IntelliJ.  Frustrating too because it seems to be the only issue I encounter with it that requires a nuclear removal.  This is the second time it has happened, luckily both times they allow me to update (since Jetbrains is apparently incapable of updating the app automatically...).